# Getting odd Error with MySQL Cursors containing a Simple Loop

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, cursors

Getting weird error with MySQL cursors. Could be trivial, but I cannot see what is going on.

Here is the error if I run it using "CALL cur();" outlined below...:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DONE' in 'field list'

This leads me to believe it is referring to my Paper_Review table. However, the Paper_Review table only contains the columns as follows:

paperID, reviewerID, score, reviewSubmissionDate, reviewInvitationDate

If I run it by highlighting the entire query, I get a different error altogether:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cur()
BEGIN
DECLARE pScore INT;
DECLARE b BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE aCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT pr.score FROM Paper_Review AS pr;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = TRUE;
OPEN aCursor;
myloop: LOOP
    FETCH aCursor INTO pScore;
    IF b THEN
        LEAVE myloop;
    END IF;
    IF pScore <> -1 THEN
        UPDATE Paper_Review AS pr
        SET pr.score = -1
        WHERE pr.reviewerID = "123" AND pr.reviewSubmissionDate < "2016-03-25";
    END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE aCursor;
END;

CALL cur();
```

To create tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE Author(
aEmail VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
fName VARCHAR(255),
lName VARCHAR(255),
bDate date,
city VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
rEmail VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
phoneNumber VARCHAR(255),
lName VARCHAR(255),
fName VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Paper(
paperID INT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(255),
abstract VARCHAR(255),
submissionDate date
);

CREATE TABLE Author_Paper(
authorID INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Author (aEmail),
paperID INT,
isContact BOOLEAN
);

ALTER TABLE Author_Paper
ADD FOREIGN KEY (paperID) REFERENCES Paper(paperID);

ALTER TABLE Author_Paper
MODIFY COLUMN authorID VARCHAR(255);

ALTER TABLE Author_Paper
ADD FOREIGN KEY (authorID) REFERENCES Author(aEmail);

CREATE TABLE Paper_Review(
paperID INT,
reviewerID VARCHAR(255),
score INT,
reviewSubmissionDate date,
reviewInvitationDate date
);

ALTER TABLE Paper_reviewpaper_review_ibfk_1
ADD FOREIGN KEY (paperID) REFERENCES Paper(paperID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (reviewerID) REFERENCES Reviewer(rEmail);

INSERT INTO Author (aEmail, fName, lName, bDate, city) VALUES("abc", "s", "b", '1981-02-1', "City");
INSERT INTO Author (aEmail, fName, lName, bDate, city) VALUES("ghi", "r", "s", '1999-01-05', "City");
INSERT INTO Reviewer (rEmail, phoneNumber, lName,fName, city) VALUES ("123", "403-333-3333", "k", "b", "City");
INSERT INTO Paper(paperID, title, submissionDate) VALUES (5, "A Paper 5", "2016-02-2");
INSERT INTO Author_Paper(authorID, paperID, isContact) VALUES ("abc", "5", true);
INSERT INTO Paper_Review(paperID, reviewerID, score, reviewSubmissionDate, reviewInvitationDate) VALUES (5, "123", 6, "2016-02-20", "2016-02-15");
```

Anything will help!

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add yozr table as text  not as image

Comment: Sorry about that, of course. The table paper_review only contains the following columns: paperID, reviewerID, Score, reviewSubmissionDate, reviewInvitationDate. I think the values themselves shouldn't be necessary. Let me know if you require more information.

Comment: To test your query i need a create table and data. there is nothing wrong that i can see, but to test  it i need data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query   and please edit your query and add not something  like code table structure as comment

Comment: I added all requirements to reproduce the problem, thanks and let me know if that works.

Comment: Paper review is enough i run your procdure and it runs with out a problem, no errors what so ever. I don't think that is a sql problem, mor a mysql problem, soemthing is wrong, restart the computer , see if there are error messages for mysql event viewer

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Paper_reviewpaper_review_ibfk_1`?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cur()
BEGIN
DECLARE pScore INT;
DECLARE b BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE aCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT pr.score FROM Paper_Review AS pr;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = TRUE;
OPEN aCursor;
myloop: LOOP
    FETCH aCursor INTO pScore;
    IF b THEN
        LEAVE myloop;
    END IF;
    IF pScore <> -1 THEN
        UPDATE Paper_Review AS pr
        SET pr.score = -1
        WHERE pr.reviewerID = "123" AND pr.reviewSubmissionDate < "2016-03-25";
    END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE aCursor;
END;

-- finalize SP definition
$$
-- restore std. delimiter
DELIMITER ;

CALL cur();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45e3a85536eaa06555de76cfd80b04b7)

Comment: Thank you for this! I am unfortunately still getting Errors above :(

Comment: *I am unfortunately still getting Errors above* Either DDLs provided in the question does not match to real ones or there are some problems in your execution environment...